# Speed up / modify tcdrain() function

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, serial-port

I'll skirt round the long and tedious story of how we got where we are, but the situation is this:

We are using half-duplex RS485 serial comms and (by necessity) driving the TX/RX flag "manually" via GPIO pin toggling. In order to make this work we're using `tcdrain()` to wait until the Tx buffer is empty before flipping back to Rx mode.

**The problem** is that `tcdrain()` seems to wait (block) for quite a while after the last character has been transmitted, which causes us a bit of a bottleneck.

I've seen suggestions that the default `tcdrain()` code just multiplies the baud rate by the (maximum) size of the serial buffer, `sleep()`s for that time period and then returns.- and I could easily believe that.

So, can anyone suggest ways to either:

- Speed up `tcdrain()` perhaps by shortening the serial buffer
- Modify `tcdrain()` (or related code/parameters) to actually wait for the last character to be sent by the hardware, or wait for a period more closely related to the buffer contents

I've grepped our (embedded) kernel (2.6.x) code and can't see any references other than a single header file (termios.h).

**Edit to add:** As per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815811/linux-serial-port-reading-can-i-change-size-of-input-buffer), if for example we could reduce the serial Tx buffer to 1 byte using an IOCTL I assume the `write()` call would/could block while chars were written, then return, which would allow us to avoid relying on `tcdrain()` and just use a very short `usleep()` before toggling the Tx/Rx pin. I will experiment when I get a moment, in the meantime any suggestions/examples welcome.

Comment: What do you mean with _TX/RX flag_? RTS/CTS? Are you at user space level?

Comment: The RS485 driver has a TX/RX control pjn whose exact name escapes me, normally you'd wire it to RTS/CTS but for hardware reasons that's not possible. It's an embedded system using a Linux SDK so we can change _anything_ but it's nicer to achieve it with standard syscalls and an unmodified kernel if possible.

Comment: Using your approach you'll not achieve a fast RTS/CTS implementation. You should thing to add kernel modulo to do the job using usart interrupts.

Comment: Have you read the kernel [Documentation/serial/serial-rs485.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/serial/serial-rs485.txt)? The `s485conf.delay_rts_before_send` and `s485conf.delay_rts_after_send` might be pertinent, depending on which driver you are using and how.

Comment: @NominalAnimal I don't think that is supported in OP's 2.6.x kernel though. Too old!

Comment: @IanAbbott: It depends. The Atmel driver got it (`.delay_rts_before_send` part, at least, which sounds suspiciously like OP's issue to me; although `.delay_rts_after_send` might fit the description better) in 2.6.35 (August 2010).

Comment: @IanAbbott is correct, that's not supported in our kernel / drivers and as said before, our hardware does not have the RTS/CTS wired out.

Comment: @NominalAnimal -- The RS-485 API in Linux has actually only been implemented in a handful of serial drivers.  In the case of Atmel, the `delay_rts_after_send` feature is implemented with a special "timeguard" hardware in the USART.  The OP could use the RS-485 API, but there's no code to port to implement what he wants.

Comment: Have you considered toggling the GPIO pin in your serial driver (i.e. a software-timer implementation of the RS-485 API)?  OR create a new ioctl() (to replace the use of tcdrain()) that would block until the transmitter is idle.

Comment: @sawdust: Yeah. Pity John U cannot/will not tell us exactly what driver he's using. If it's a standard serial driver, then we could easily check the kernel sources to see the exact implementation. If it is an out-of-tree, secret-sauce driver, then who cares? You cook your own stew and get to eat it too, if you don't wanna share; but then asking others to share their spices and 'erbs for free, is quite rude...

Comment: @sawdust we can toggle GPIO from userspace rather than mod the driver. Can you explain the ioctl() idea, that could be exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @NominalAnimal - serial driver is 8250/16550 but as per my post, grepping the entire kernel source we have does not find `tcdrain()` source anywhere. I'm not holding out on you, if I had found more info I'd have posted it so you can drop the sarcasm any time.

Comment: @JohnU: There is no *"8250/16550"* serial driver in the Linux kernel. There are [quite a few of them](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/tty/serial/8250). Use `ls -ld /sys/module/*8250* /sys/module/*16550*` to see which modules the kernel uses. Can you tell us what exact kernel version your embedded system is based on? (When it diverged from vanilla, that is.) The RS-485 support may be backportable. It all depends on these nitty gritty details.

Comment: `sys/module/8250` is the one in use. System is a TI DM368 SoC. Kernel is 2.6.37 I believe, the Linux SDK is provided by TI so I don't have a good handle on how much custom code there may be in there.

Comment: @JohnU: [TI's kernel code](http://software-dl.ti.com/dsps/dsps_public_sw/sdo_sb/targetcontent/dvsdk/DVSDK_4_00/latest/index_FDS.html) requires registration. The DM368 parts have not been pushed upstream (not even to nsekhar's kernel repo), so it seems you and other DM368 users are on TI's mercy. Compare your `arch/arm/mach-davinci/` to [nsekhar's](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/nsekhar/linux-davinci.git/tree/arch/arm/mach-davinci) or [current vanilla](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/mach-davinci).

Comment: TI are probably too embarrassed to push it upstream.